# Explanation of loop which calculates the exponential through sum

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, sum, exponential

```
public class exp {
    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        int i, numTerms = 10;
        double fac, exp = 0.0;
        for (i = 0, fac = 1.0; i < numTerms; i++, fac *= i) {
            exp += 1.0/fac;
        }
        System.out.println("exp(1) = "+exp);
        System.out.println("Error is "+Math.abs(Math.E-exp));
    }
}
```

I'm new to Java and I would like to clarify how this loop works. The loop's supposed to approximate the exponential to the power of 1:

[image]

> If I type in for numTerms= 0, it gives me that exp(1)= 0 . Is it
>   because this loop does not add anything so it gives me 0? How is 0
>   derived exactly?
>
> If I type in for numTerms = 1, it gives me that expr(1)=1 . Since
>   first iteration: i=1, then fac=1 and then exp = 0 + 1/1=1 . Right?
>
> If I type in for numTerms = 2, it gives me that exp(1)=2. Why? By my
>   logic, by second iteration, i=2, fac= 1*2=2, and then exp =1+1/2= 3/2 .

What is the mistake I'm making?

Also, what is the point of initializing fac and exp to be 0.0? (3rd line of code)

Comment: There is always the same number of iterations of the loop as the value of numTerms, this seems to be something you have misunderstood

Comment: Something you should look at https://cdn.programiz.com/sites/tutorial2program/files/c-for-loop.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This whole code is a numerical method of calculating the mathematical constant `e` (base of natural logarithm), but you know that already.

The syntax of for loop allows to declare multiple variables, but they must be of same type.
That's why the `i` and `fac` were declared before the loop.
The `double fac, exp = 0.0;` statement declares both variables but initializes only `exp`, similar thing goes to `int i...`.

The precision of calculation made with any numerical method strictly depend on the amount of steps (in this case, the given number of iterations).
For insufficient number of steps, the calculated value can be very unaccurate (or as in the case of making `numTerms=0` or `numTerms=1` - a completely wrong output).

You are right for the 0.

For the `numTerms=1`, it's 1, because for the first iteration the `i` equal 0, the `fac` is initialized to `1.0`. The `fac*=i` is calculaded after code block.

For `numTerms=2`: If the `i` reaches 2, the condition of loop is false:

```
i < numTerms     -     2 < 2     <- which is false
```

When the loop condition is false then it doesn't execute it's block.
The part `i++, fac *= i` might be confusing, but for loop goes like this:

```
for(initialization;condition;increment/update)
```

Before start it goes with initialization (if there are variables), then it checks condition (the variable could already exceed the limit in condition). If condition is true, the code block is called.
After code block, the `increment/update` expressions are called, then before running the code block, it again checks the condition.
So it would go:

> 1st iteration: i=0, fac=1 -> exp+=1/1 => exp=1
>   2nd iteration: i=1, fac=1 -> exp+=1/1 => exp=2

After the 2nd iteration, the "update" expressions are evaluated making: i=2, fac=2 - but for `i=2` the loop condition is false.

I don't quite understand the "How is 0 derived exactly?" from your questions, but I hope I already answered it :)

And maybe an interesting fact. You've asked there about the initialization of `i` and `fac`, where it actually happens in for loop. But it's possible to do:

```
int i = 0, numTerms = 2;  //the i is not only declared but also initialized here
double fac = 1.0, exp = 0.0; //same with fac
for (;i < numTerms; ++i, fac *= i) //so no need to do it again in for
```

The for loop can be rewritten to while and vice versa.
Writing `for(;;)` is same as `while(true)`.